# Dont work split(). javascript

Tags: javascript, split

there is a line.
how do I split it into an array via separator ",".
If you try to split, the same line is returned

```js
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
console.log(str);
console.log(typeof(str));

var name = str.split(",");

console.log(name);
console.log(typeof(name));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` is a global property of Window object that is accessible throughout the JavaScript runtime and this is always a `String` type so despite of `str.split(',')` returning array of elements, due to its default type it is converted back to the string values. Thus, you need to use different variable name say, `_name`.

```js
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
console.log(str);
console.log(typeof(str));

var _name = str.split(',');
console.log(_name);
console.log(typeof(_name));
```

Comment: thank you so much @Ankit